# bash script - request input via gui

Tags: shell-script, gui, nemo, user-input

I'm currently writing a nemo action script in bash, and I need a way to get input from the user.

How?, the terminal isn't showing when running an action script.

is there anyway to popup a query window in the GUI to ask the user for input?

Comment: Which shell is using it?

Comment: @Mareyes what do you mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zenity is a good tool for that.

```
user_input=$(zenity --entry)
```

That assigns to variable `user_input` whatever the user types in the GUI window, unless the user presses cancel, in which case the exit code is not zero.

```
user_input=$(zenity --entry)
if [ $? = 0 ]; then 
    echo "User has pressed OK. The input was:"
    echo "$user_input"
else
    echo "User has pressed cancel"
fi
```

Gxmessage is an alternative, with very similar syntax.

```
user_input=$(gxmessage --entry "Enter your input")
```

More information in [`man zenity`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/zenity.1.html) and [`man gxmessage`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/gxmessage/gxmessage.1.en.html).

Comment: a follow-up question: it works great, but I'm seeing this notice; Gtk-Message: 08:28:17.401: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged..... have no idea what they mean..

Comment: @JoBe That is no problem. https://askubuntu.com/q/844323

Answer (score 7):

- If you want to stay in the shell use `dialog` (On pretty much every distribution it is already installed by default).
  Before using it, read the manpage so that you can configure it to do exactly what you want. A tiny example:

```bsh
dialog --inputbox "Please input something" 0 0 2> /tmp/file_that_will_contain_your_input
```

- If want a X11-window to appear, checkout xdialog. But I recommend staying in the shell:
  Writing scripts that partially use X11 and partially the console is asking for problems without gaining any advantage.
  The syntax for `xdialog` is pretty much equal to that of `dialog` for compatibility reasons. So if you put a `x` in front of the example above it would do exactly the same but with a X11-window instead. Again, check out the manpage for more info.

Comment: @Quasímodo The problem is that GUI is a rather vague term... I would consider `dialog` also a GUI. Anyway, I followed your advice and mentioned that the `xdialog` manpage and the fact that the syntax is compatible

Comment: @Garo but dialog is pure shell?, it don't display anything in the "GUI" (windows)? and since the terminal isn't showing when you're running a nemo.action script..  however, I've now learned about a new command (and I'll test it out)

Comment: @Quasimodo according to shell there isn't any command called xdialog...

Comment: @JoBe You probably do not have the package installed. Depending on your distribution, you do it in different ways. For Debian, `apt install nxdialog`.

Comment: @Garo regarding "The problem is that GUI is a rather vague term": some use the term Character User Interface (CUI) to refer to a UI that uses text based constructs to emulate a "true" GUI, which disambiguates the matter. Unfortunately the term if far from universally used or even recognised.